# How to query nearest geopoints in Firestore for a Flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on an app which can show 5-10 nearest GeoPoints from Firestore database for a Flutter app. Is it possible to do this in the Flutter app itself or should I make a Firebase cloud function? How do I query the nearest GeoPoints?

Comment: First you would need a database of geo points, inside firebase , or as you figured it out you should create a cloud function that would collect the geo points for the user inputted geo points and return the nearest geo points. Now fluter gives you full power to display the result in a creative UI way. You could also use the first party Goole maps plugin to show the geo points

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do a query nearest geopoints in Firebase Database for a Flutter app.

1. [GeoFlutterFire](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire)
2. [Firestore Helpers](https://pub.dev/packages/firestore_helpers)

You can have a look into the following code to have an idea of how to query nearest geopoints Using GeoFlutterFire :

```
// Create a geoFirePoint
GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: 19.9132, longitude: 72.623603);

// get the collection reference or query
var collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("MY_COLLECTION");
double radius = 50;
String field = 'position';

Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo.collection(collectionRef: 
       collectionReference).within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field);
```